# Broadcast text using eddystone url layout (or altbeacon)

Tags: ibeacon, altbeacon, android-ibeacon, eddystone, eddystone-url

I have a `16 length` string that I would like to broadcast as the identifier, which the app uses to do certain actions.

Relatively new to the different beacon layouts, so would love to get the right opinion. I was thinking of doing it the following ways

> hex encode the string and use it as identifier in eddystone url layout

But the 16 length takes up 32 bytes and doesn't help

Another option is to use [altbeacon](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html) library like below.

> byte[] dataBytes = new String("16 length string").getBytes()
>
> Identifier identifier = Identifier.fromBytes(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.length, false);

I am not sure either works mainly because of the 16 length string. Is there a better way to achieve or do it at all in first place?

Comment: If you can encode as ASCII 8 bit you can send a 16 character string as 16 bytes.  Will this work?